# Post-rooting: updating Android and modifying system files?

Tags: updates, root-access

So at last I rooted my tablet (without a custom ROM). Then when I checked for new updates I received the message "Your device has been modified" so I don't get any new updates. So my first question is:

**1-Can I update the operating system (and not the firmware) myself?**   My kernel version is 3.4.0.

Now since Android is a Linux-like OS, I expected to be able to tweak the system by editing the files in the /etc folder. For example I hoped I could manage app permissions this way.  But when I open the files on /etc/permissions or /system/etc/permissions I don't understand much. So:

**2-Is it a good idea to modify system setting files and if yes, is there any (official) reference manual?** 
[I hope the last question is not interpreted as "suggestions request".]

Comment: To answer your question, 1) To be able to update Android through official channel, your bootloader needs to be locked for OTA upgrades. 2) You can certainly update system files - *you're on your own there if you mess up!* As to regards references, use the AOSP source code as a guide, as well as the API documents, and newsgroups. **Question for you** What device and what version of Android are you referring to?

Comment: Actually, for 1) above, I just checked on my handset - bootloader is untouched and locked, but rooted, ran a check for system updates, system updates refused to run, just be aware of it, the general consensus is that, if the bootloader is unlocked - it will not work hence why I asked you what device and Android version you're referring to :)

Comment: My device is a Galaxy note 10.1" 2014 LTE and the Android version is 4.3.

Comment: Android uses the Linux kernel, but its userspace is quite different from a GNU/Linux system.  Don't expect to be able to configure everything through text files in `/etc`.  And if you go modifying system files or replacing the kernel, don't expect official updates to work properly.